# Why does this function not work for negative numbers?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I an using the following function to calculate the set bits in an integer, and it works for positive numbers, but not for negative numbers. Can anyone explain why?

```
int CountSetBits(int number)
{
    int count = 0;
    while (number > 0)
    {
        count += (number & 0x01);
        number >>= 1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: define 'doesn't work'. What do you expect and what do you get? And perhaps you need to look up 'sign extension'.

Answer (score 6):

```
    while (number > 0)
```

Will immediately end (since number < 0 from the onset)

You can force it to treat the number as unsigned:

```
    unsigned int new_number = number;
```

And then it should work with `new_number` (this works because of how the sign bit is implemented)

Comment: Slight nitpick, this assumes 2's complement, which is not actually mandated by the standard but all modern machines use it.  The standard does however guarantee that if using 2's complement then the conversion is bit-wise exact.